# Will android kill my daemon which is running as root?

Tags: android, android-ndk, daemon, root, kill

I have an app that (has a part that) needs to always run; it's not started as a service, the app starts a daemon (written in c) which runs as root.

Is android going to kill it on me to reclaim memory? Does it running as root protect me from this? If not, what can I do to ensure that it never dies and if it does, it starts again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your daemon is a pure native application (for example, started through the system's inittab), not something running within the context of an APK, then Android will never kill it. At least, in my situation which is exactly this, the only time my daemon has ever terminated is just prior to my fixing a SIGSEGV ;)

Answer (score 0):

I havent worked with android in awhile now, nor have I worked with root running process. But I do believe that regardless of what user your app is running, android OS might issue it a 'do stop' and then potentially a 'kill' command if memory does get low. The reason I say this is because similar to the full Linux kernel, if it needs memory, it WILL find a way to get it. I have an HTC phone and I have actually seen the kernel kill HTC sense to get RAM, which essentially resets the phone. There are ways to set when an app should be started, I believe you can set hooks that say when an app should be started based off of phone events. Similar to how a txt msg app will start when a phone receives an txt, or how an alarm app will still go off even if you kill the app in a task manager. I believe you can set these in the apps xml config.

Good luck!

Comment: that's very interesting, but how do you know it killed sense to reclaim memory? ie how do you know it wasn't just sense crashing?

Comment: I have no way of knowing for sure that it isnt sense crashing... but all signs point to this. I have never had sense do this on its own when it is the main application in focus. It only gets killed when I am using an application that I know is sucking up a lot of RAM, and Android developer documentation states that this is the procedure. Since Sense isn't directly part of the OS, and more of a layer it is my best guess that this is what is happening

Comment: I suppose if I was really determined to know if that was the case I could turn on debugging and watch the system log through eclipse while loading an app that sucks up RAM. theoretically the sys log will print out when issuing the kill command and which applications were affected. This would prove my assumptions.